Why template function which is constrained to work with integrals, is working fine with char as well?
I have a simple cpp template function as follows.
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

template <typename T> requires std::integral<T>
T add(T a, T b)
{
    std::cout << "From within the function, typeid(T).name(): " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "From within the function, typeid(a).name(): " << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;
    return a + b;
}

Now from main, I call it as follows.
int main() 
{
    char a_0{10};
    char a_1{20};

    std::cout << "typeid(a_0).name(): " << typeid(a_0).name() << std::endl;

    auto result_a = add(a_0, a_1);

    std::cout << "result_a : " << static_cast<int>(result_a) << std::endl;
}

I am expecting a compilation error because while the type parameters are constrained to be integral, I am passing char arguments.
Why is it working?
I compiled with the following command.
g++ "-static" -o main.exe .\*.cpp -std=c++20

I get the following output.
typeid(a_0).name(): c
typeid(T).name(): c
typeid(a).name(): c
result_a : 30


char is really an integer type, with a small and limited range.

I come from C# school, seems unnatural to me.

@VivekDev It's not ideal, but it's for compatibility with C.

Why's it unnatural? A character in almost any language is just a number, you can do arithmetic on it, you can even print out it's numerical value, therefore it has all the same properties as any other integral type

I come from C# school You might want to type cs, like you did it with C++ in the title and the head sentence.

It's a historical accident. Original C had int and short, but didn't have anything like int8_t, so people just used  char instead. And there we are!

A char is actually an integral type.


I am expecting a compilation error because while the type parameters are constrained to be integral, I am passing char arguments.
Why is it working?

Because char is considered an integral type in C++.
From cppreference.com, the std::is_integral :

template< class T >
struct is_integral; (since C++11) 

std::is_integral is a UnaryTypeTrait.
Checks whether T is an integral type. Provides the member constant value which is equal to true, if T is the type bool, char, char8_t(since C++20), char16_t, char32_t, wchar_t, short, int, long, long long, or any implementation-defined extended integer types, including any signed, unsigned, and cv-qualified variants. Otherwise, value is equal to false.

Therefore, if you want to restrict your function to work only with larger integer types and exclude char, you could modify your constraint accordingly.
